# How would I assign values to an object on creation, that takes String and ArrayList values as params?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am loading an initial dataset into a database using Spring's CommandLineRunner. When creating a new object, the object requires a few String values and then an ArrayList value. Is there a way to initialize the values for both the String values and the ArrayList values within the new object declaration?

I can successfully create the object by passing in null for the ArrayList but what I am trying to do is add in String literals within the declaration.

```
//declared constructor in the Person class.

public Person(String name, String address, ArrayList<String> values){}
```

```
//implemented method from CommandLineRunner within the DatabaseLoader class.

@Override
public void run(String... args) throw Exception {
    this.repo.save(new Person("Joe", "123 Main St",  **null**));
```

In order to have the code run successfully assigning null to the ArrayList works, but what I am trying to do is declare the ArrayList similar to how the String literals are passed on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use

```
Collections.emptyList();
```

or

```
Collections.singletonList(value);
```

or, if you have multiple values

```
Arrays.asList(„value1“, „value2”, ...);
```

or with recent versions of Java (JDK11 and above)

```
List.of(„value1“, „value2“, ...);
```

With all of these methods you need to be aware of the fact that the returned `List` is immutable. Adding or removing elements to the `List` will result in an `UnsupportedOperationException`. If you want a modifiable `List` you can simply use the `ArrayList(Collection)` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Arrays.asList("val1", "val2",...)`